# What is the easiest way to use logger on a website that is hosted on Appharbor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, appharbor

I have a web site deployed on AppHarbor.

What is the easiest way to use logger on the deployed site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest hands down: Use Log4Net/NLog and the logentries add-on:

https://logentries.com/doc/appharbor/

Comment: this addon is not available anymore?

Comment: it is for me (currently only as trial)

Comment: can you try click on the download page (see inside the link you sent me)

Comment: As Dan says, you have to enable it in your AppHarbor account. The link gives detailed instructions on how to start using it, but in short you have to: 1. activate the add-on in AppHarbor, 2. add the necessary logging libraries to your app and 3. add logging statements to your code. Read the page for more info.

Comment: To add it to your account, sign in on AppHarbor, go to Add-Ons, click on the See More link under Logentries and then on the Install button